# Why diffrence is not visible after indexing as compare to fulltext search in mysql laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, indexing, eloquent

I did indexing for my laravel project . Table is having almost 5000 records query took almost 1 seconds while using where condistion only fetch 600 records. but before and after indexing i didn't see any change in query speed. it is same as before.

on the other hand once i used fulltext search indexing on another project it increases speed of query 4 times.

What is the reason behind it.

for indexing i was using laravel method `index()` in migration

```
$table->integer('id')->index();
```

Comment: you don't need to use id as index, read [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: this example its about other columns as well

Comment: Show us the SQL for the query.  The title talks about FULLTEXT, but the body does not; elaborate.